# Intershop Studio 4.9.0 gradle cartridges problem

Tags: eclipse-plugin, intershop

I have a problem with Intershop Studio 4.9.0 not showing java and pipelets from gradle system cartridges. I upgraded Studio by extracting new zip file and just copy workspace from Studio 4.7. In old Studio I don't have this problem.

[image]

System cartridges opened in server folder shows java and pipelets without problem, but pipeline editor looks for pipelets in gradle cartridges and because of that all system pipelets can't be resolved.

[image]

Is this issue with latest Studio or something is wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem and already fixed in the master branch. An updated version of Intershop-Studio will be available very soon.